Fundamental group of the n-fold dunce cap
This is the definition of the n-fold dunce cap from Munkres' Topology:

Definition. Let $ n $ be a positive integer with $ n > 1 $. Let $ r : S^1 \rightarrow S^1 $ be rotation through the angle $ 2\pi /n $,
mapping the point $ (\cos\theta, \sin\theta) $ to the point $
 (\cos(\theta + 2\pi /n), \sin(\theta + 2\pi /n)) $. Form a quotient
space $ X $ from the unit ball $ B^2 $ by identifying each point $ x $
of $ S^1 $ with the points $ r(x), r^2(x), ..., r^{n-1}(x) $. We shall
show that $ X $ is a compact Hausdorff space; we call it the $ n
 $-fold dunce cap.


Theorem 73.4. The fundamental group of the n-fold dunce cap is a cyclic group of order $n$.
Proof. Let $h : B^2 \to X$ be the quotient map, where $X$ is the n-fold dunce cap. Set $A = h(S^1)$. Let $p = (1,0) \in S^1$ and let $a
 = h(p)$. Then $h$ maps the arc $C$  of $S^1$ running from $p$ to $r(p)$ onto $A$; it identifies the end points of  $C$ but is
otherwise injective. Therefore, $A$ is homeomorphic to a circle, so
its fundamental  group is infinite cyclic. Indeed, if $\gamma$ is the
path $$
     \gamma(t) = (\cos(2\pi t/n), \sin(2\pi t/n)) $$ in $S^1$ from $p$ to $r(p)$, then $\alpha = h \circ \gamma$ represents a generator of
$\pi_1(A,a)$.
Now the class of loop $$  
    f = y * ((r \circ y) * (r^2 \circ y)\ * \dots * \ (r^{n-1} \circ y)) $$ generates $\pi(S^1, p)$. Since $h(r^m(x)) = h(x)$ for all $x$
and $m$, the loop $h \circ f$ equals the n-fold product $\alpha *
(\alpha * (\cdots * \alpha))$. The theorem follows.

I don't understand exactly how the above proof shows that the fundamental group is a cyclic group of order n? why $\alpha *
(\alpha * (\cdots * \alpha))$ equals $\alpha$ and why all the proof is about $A$ what about $h(Int(B^2))$? why $\alpha = h \circ \gamma$ represents a generator of
$\pi_1(A,a)$, $h$ is not a homeomorphism.

I don't have the book handy, so take this with a grain of salt, but is this relying on van Kampen's theorem? You've shown the fundamental group is cyclic once you show $A$ is a circle, then you use the disk (which gives a null homotopy of its boundary) to show the fundamental group's generator has order $n$.

this section is in the chapter named Seifert -van Kampen theorem and it has been proved in previous sections but I don't know the exact connection

Munkres is using his Theorem 72.1 here (in turn based on the Seifert-van Kampen theorem), which describes exactly how to compute the fundamental group. Indeed, it tells us that $\pi_1(A,a)\rightarrow\pi_1(X,a)$ induced by the inclusion is surjective and its kernel is the normal subgroup generated by the image of $h_{\ast}\colon\pi_1(S^1,p)\rightarrow\pi_1(A,a)$. The subspace $A$ is, as Munkres explains, homeomorphic to a circle, so $\pi_1(A,a)\cong\mathbb{Z}$ and the loop $\alpha=h\circ\gamma$ is a generator (the fundamental group of the circle and its generators are explicitly described in chapter $54$). The group $\pi_1(S^1,p)\cong\mathbb{Z}$ is cyclic generated by the element represented by the loop $f=\gamma\ast((r\circ\gamma)\ast(\dotsc\ast(r^{n-1}\circ\gamma)))$, so its image under $h$ is $h\circ f=(h\circ\gamma)\ast((hr\circ\gamma)\ast(\dotsc\ast(hr^{n-1}\circ\gamma)))=\alpha\ast(\alpha\ast(\dotsc\ast\alpha))=\alpha^n$ (recall that $hr=h$ by definition). It follows that $\pi_1(X,a)\cong\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, generated by the equivalence class of $\alpha$.
